# How to change IP of Jupyter Notebook with VPN

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, vpn

I am scraping Data from Google, Bt it is showing captcha again so i am using IP Rotator software bt it is not Rotating IP of Jupyter Notebook.
Please tell me way to change IP of Jupyter notebook with VPN Rotator. Or If you have other to scrape data from google Please suggest me. Thank you

Comment: FYI it's scrape and scraping (and scraper, scraped) not scrap or scrapping. To scrap, scrapping, scrapper and scrapped are about throwing things away like rubbish, or fighting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.